# How to save trimmed wave file in python?

Tags: python, numpy, speech-recognition, microphone, wave

I am trying to record microphone input, perform some endpointing algorithm that will endpoint speech and save new wave file with speech only.

I managed to save a file but when I play the recording it plays half of the speech sequence.

1) What format should the array be in in order for me to succesfuly save it?

2) How can I convert it to that format?

I am using the following algorithm for microphone recording and the mistake is somewhere in the way I save the file:

If I call writeframes(frames) it nicely saves complete 3second mic input.

```
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16                # We use 16bit format per sample
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
CHUNK = 1024                            # 1024bytes of data red from a buffer
RECORD_SECONDS = 3
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "file.wav"

audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# start Recording
stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT,
                    channels=CHANNELS,
                    rate=RATE, input=True,
                    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print "recording..."
frames = []
for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)
print "finished recording"
# stop Recordings
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
audio.terminate()

frames = ''.join(frames)

# important! convert from string to int
amplitudeSamples = np.fromstring(frames, np.int16)

# Perform endpointing algorithm where I compute start and end indexes 
# within amplitudeSamples array

voiceSample = amplitudeSamples[start:end]

# Here lies the problem
waveFile = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
waveFile.setnchannels(1)
waveFile.setsampwidth(2)
waveFile.setframerate(RATE)
waveFile.writeframes(voiceSample) 
#waveFile.writeframesraw(voiceSample) # doesn't work also
waveFile.close()
```

Comment: Are you sure that the algorithm that checks start and end is doing its job correctly?

Comment: Yes, I have plotted amplitudeSamples and vertical edges of start and end index and they fit really fine.

Comment: What about the parameters in setnchannels and setsampwidth calls? Are they correct?

Comment: I record it with 1 channel, setsampwidth I guess its 2 because I record it with paInt16 which is 2byte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the numpy array to a string before writing it:

```
wavFile.writeframes(voiceSample.tostring())
```

Comment: Also possible with soundfile.write('bla.wav', voiceSignal, 44100) using soundfilde library

Comment: See also 'wavio' on pypi.